# Prove that $3x-x^3<\frac2{\sin2x}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Prove that $$3x-x^3<\frac2{\sin2x},\forall x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$$

I have tried by proving that $$3x-x^3<\frac9{5\pi}x+\frac32<\frac2{\sin2x},\forall x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$$ with Jensen's inequality, but I hoped this problem would have a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\sin 2x\le1 \implies \frac{2}{\sin 2x}\ge 2$$

and

$$3x-x^3\le 2$$

Comment: Thank you, I was foolish to see this.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure. And no you're not foolish.  I have missed the tree in the forest many times.  It is easy to do.  You're fine!

Answer (score 2):

The range of the function $f(x)=3x-x^3$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ is $f(x)\in(0,2)$.

For the function $g(x)=\dfrac2{\sin2x}$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ the range is clearly $g(x)\in(2,\infty)$.

The inequality is quite clear now.

Comment: Just like mine ;-))

Comment: Yeah well the mobile site does not display answers in real-time.

Comment: No worry.  I've posted answers like that many times.  It's good to see alignment with our answers!

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=(3x-x^3)\sin(2x)$ over $I=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. It is a non-negative function since $\pi^2<12$. Since over the same interval we have $\sin(2x)\leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}(2x)(\pi-2x)$, it is enough to prove that:

$$ \forall x\in I,\qquad x^2(3-x^2)(\pi-2x)\leq \frac{\pi^2}{4}. \tag{1}$$
By differentiation we may locate the absolute maximum of $g(x)=x^2(3-x^2)(\pi-2x)$ over $I$ around $x=0.88552583$. In such a point $g(x)$ is about $2.38141<2.4674<\frac{\pi^2}{4}$, so $(1)$ holds.

Comment: It's much simpler.  $2\csc (2x)\ge 2$ and $3x-x^3\le 2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: oh, nice. I thought it was possible to separate the two functions by putting a line in between (since they are a convex and a concave function), but I didn't try the most simple approach :D

Comment: I began thinking about ways to do this and then it just struck me.  It's very easy to miss the tree from the forest so they say.

Comment: @Dr.MV "sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees" is the phrase that springs to mind

Comment: @DavidQuinn [This is the saying](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_forest_for_the_trees) that I was paraphrasing.

Comment: @Dr.MV. Yes of course, but that's American or Australian English, whereas the original British English phrase has wood not forest. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Proverbs_of_John_Heywood. Sorry to be splitting hairs...

Comment: @davidquinn Thanks for the up vote!  Much appreciative!!  And thanks for clarifying the saying.  It's always a bit interesting to see the local English language transform.  Language evolution or devolution is an amazing process.